# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter after making changes in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I added below snippet in my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and got below exception:

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

after removing the above tag, this spring application is running fine. I wish to know why?

POM.XML
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sas</groupId>
    <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
    <name>ApartmentMgmt</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>`

        `<!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>`


        `<!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>`
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>`
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>`
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>`

```
`   <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
            `
`   <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>`
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>`
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>`

    `<!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>`  

    `<!-- Need this for json to/from object -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>`

    `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>`
`   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>     
</dependencies>`
`<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <wtpContextName>spring4ajax</wtpContextName>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>`
```

`

Comment: Add the whole `pom.xml`..

Comment: Did you add `spring-boot-starter-web` in your dependencies?

Comment: after adding dependency tag by @funtik, my pom.xml looks like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `spring-boot-starter-parent` does not include dependency to `springframework.web` library.

Add this to your pom.xml, to fix your issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `3.2.5.RELEASE` is a bit old!

Comment: `Missing artifact org.springframework:org.springframework.web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE` getting this error in pom.xml, was getting same for 3.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: do you have spring maven repo included in your pom?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add jackson dependencies in you `pom.xml`.

Please refer below link to include relevant jackson module

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

or you can include spring web module in case using spring web features . It will bring all dependencies automatically:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```